# Show that the following series is always convergent.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I need to show that the following series is always convergent:
$$\left|\left|v\right|\right|=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left|\mathcal{A}^kv\right|}{R^k},$$

where $\mathcal{A}$ is a linear operator and $R>\rho\left(\mathcal{A}\right)=\underset{i}{max}|\lambda_i|$. The R.H.S. of the inequality is the spectral radius of the linear operator $\mathcal{A}$.

I know that i need to show that there exists some $C$ such that $\left|\left|\mathcal{A}\right|\right|_2\leq Cr^n$. Thereafter i propably need to show that the sum is bounded by some series involving the above mentioned $C$.

But i cant seem to do so. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Take $r$ so $\rho(A) < r < R$.
By Gelfand's [spectral radius formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius),
$\|A^k\|^{1/k} < r$ for sufficiently large $k$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm induced by the norm $|\cdot |$, and then $|A^k v|/R^k \le \|A^k\| |v|/R^k <
(r/R)^k |v|$ so the series converges.